# Which statistical Test should I use/ Comparing 2 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am new to statistics, can someone guide me regarding the test I should use to compare the foot dimensions of 9 subjects to footwear dimensions (we have 2 footwear brands).
So, to simplify, I have data of normalised ratio foot width wrt footlength (and other dimensions also) of 9 subjects which needs to be compared to normalised foot width wrt foot length of shoe X(only 1 value not 9).

To make it easier, I simply mean..I have 9 rows for each foot dimension (27 dimensions in all) Same 27 values for each footwear. 1st comparison will be FW vs FW_P and next will be FW vs FW_E (not shown here). then Same thing for all other 26 dimensions. But, the problem is only 1 row in Fw_P, therefore it is not a distribution

If I use SPSS to check normality, Foot width of subjects shapiro wilk test p value> 0.05.
I cannot use paired t-test to compare the 2 ratios as the shoe ratio is just 1 value and not a distribution.
What should I do?
Should I use non parametric test...Wilcoxan Signed rank (duplicating the shoe ratios to 9 times) OR should I use 1 sample T test considering data to be parametric based.

I am attaching an image for reference.
[image]
Please help. Your suggestions and guidance will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clearly state what your desired test is:  For example the $H0: mean(FW) =mean(Fw_P)$ or is it something else. Also for the pair T test, if distribution of the differences is normal then one meets the requirement for the test.

Comment: Let's check it's clear what data you have: (a) 9 subjects, each with their own normalized foot measurement, and (b) 2 brands, also with one normalized foot measurement per brand. So 9 numbers for the subjects and 2 numbers for the brands?

Comment: I have 9 rows for each foot dimension (27 dimensions in all) Same 27 values for each footwear. 1st comparison will be FW vs FW_P and next will be FW vs FW_E (not shown here). then Same thing for all other 26 dimensions. But, the problem is only 1 row in Fw_P, therefore it is not a distribution.  Which test can I use? Parametric/ Non-paramteric. And if wilcoxan sign rank...should I copy the value of fw_p 9 times like I did in the image attached above?